# Where did this style come from?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I'm just curious... where did this style for StackExchange advertisements come from?

[Add image http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/starcraft-ad-zerg.jpg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/359/)  [Add image http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/starcraft-ad-protoss.jpg](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/875/) [add image http://ads.stackoverflow.com/ads/starcraft-ad-cheese.jpg](http://ads.stackoverflow.com/a.aspx?Task=Click&ZoneID=4&CampaignID=1231&AdvertiserID=5&BannerID=1995&SiteID=1&RandomNumber=1457209713&Keywords=)

I saw it on StackOverflow a couple minutes ago.

I've seen a few ads for StackExchange sites in public beta, but not one like this.

**Edit:** I know where the style itself came from... I'm wondering why its there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmmm maybe it is supposed to be similar to [...](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/launch?ref=/sc2/)

The team is obviously trying to capitalize on the recent popularity of Star Craft II to help attract people to the gaming site.

They must have deemed that it was worth their time/money to design an ad specifically to target people who play Star Craft II.

Comment: +1 for beating me to it, although I probably would have been a bit snarkier about it. ;)

Comment: @gnovice Feel free to post your answer.  If it makes me chuckle I'll prolly upvote it.

Comment: I'm not asking where the style itself came from. I'm asking why certain proposals are getting styled and others not... better change my question.

Comment: @George, I added some info.

Comment: Pretty sensible explanation. +1